# Aftdr opening yeast

Tags: yeast

I have just used dried yeast for a bread in the bread maker but there is still a lot left how long will it still be good to use after opening it and closing it properly because the booklet of the bread maker says once opened throw it away  up I find that a waste

Answer (score 0):

My dried yeast keeps well enough in the fridge after opening. It is essentially freeze dried, as long as you keep it air tight and in the fridge it should last a long time, even well after the best before date. I know someone still using dried bakers yeast first opened in the year 2000 so I wouldn't worry.